# Android save data from Amazon API locally to reduce load times?

Tags: android, database, api, mobile, amazon-product-api

I'm a new Android developer and could use some advice on a problem I've come across.

I have an app which is querying data from the Amazon Product API on almost every activity you open. I'm able to get the data, but the activities take forever to load because I'm constantly running API queries.

The app is basically a video game review app. It wouldn't be uncommon for users to load the same data for a game multiple times. I'm thinking that making api calls for the same data over and over again is very inefficient.

My question is in this scenario, should I be saving game data to a local, or even remote (Firebase) database every time data is retrieved from the Amazon API? And then whenever data needs to be retrieved, I check first to see if it's present in the database before making the API call?

If this is correct, where should I be saving the data (shared prefs, SQLlite, internal storage, etc.)? If not, what can I do to make the app pull & display data faster?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that activities take forever to load, I assume that you are not making these calls from within the Activities. And lets answer your questions one by one.

1) Shared Prefs are not a good option. (Try to use Shared prefs only when you have a bunch of things to persist). While in this case if you want to save effort of writing helper classes for database you could serialize the data (Internal Storage). And its preferable to store data locally in my opinion.

2) Do not always request the data.Only update it when the user wants the data to be refreshed (hustle free, user presses a refresh button). Or you could update data after fixed time intervals. This can involve upgrading reviews in background even when the application is not running by starting *Service* using *Alarm Manager*. You will have to read about it though.